# The package could not be installed error on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

The package could not be installed.: PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means that the Jetpack software could not be extracted from the zip archive. 
    Can you please check that your web server has available space on the volume where WordPress is installed and that you're not running into quota issues 
   (if applicable)?

Comment: How in the world did you guess that this had anything to do with Jetpack?

Answer (score 0):

The PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature error is caused by one of two things as below:

**Case 1**: There’s a problem with the zip file or it’s format.

It’s possible that the plugin zip file became corrupted when it was downloaded. Try downloading the zip file manually and install (or update manually by deactive and delete plugin, then add new plugin with your downloaded zip file)

**Case 2**: Server Disk Space Issue

If you still receive the same error while trying to install the zip manually, then it may mean that there’s not enough storage space on your host for WordPress to be able to unzip and upload the contents of the file. To confirm this, try to upload other files to your site, such as an image, video or other plugin. If you’re not able to upload large files, then storage space is likely the issue.